# Unzip password-encrypted files in c#

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, unzip

does anybody know the unzip tool from info-zip?
I would use that program in my .NET application. First I give the user the possibility to choose a zip file and the target folder over my GUI and then I start a new process with the following command:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c unzip -d target-dir zip-file");
```

That works pretty much so far. But now I would be also able to extract password-encrypted archives. So I placed a text field to enter the password on my form and send it with the -P option to the unzip tool.
But is there any possibility to check weather the archive is encrypted before displaying the password field? Because I will only prompt for a password if any is needed.

Comment: I imagine a zip tool would be required to check that.  You're already using one called info-zip, right?  Does that tool have any functionality to check this?  If not then I guess you might try a different tool.  Maybe something like DotNetZip.

Comment: Well, I guess you could read the stderr and see if it says you need a password, then prompt the user. You are kind of at the mercy of whatever toolkit you use here.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)? No need to run a separte commandline and it supports unzipping secured archives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use unzip, you could run first unzip -Z and the 5th element returned from that will be a 't' (text) or a 'b' (binary).  If they capital, then the archive is encrypted.

References:

[ZipInfo Manual](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipinfo.html)

[Unzip Manual](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html)